# QueryDsl invert manyToMany join

Tags: java, spring, jpa, querydsl

Given we have the following entities that form a many-to-many relationship:

```
@Entity
public class A {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
        name = "A_B",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_a"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_b"))
    private Set<B> listing;
}

@Entity
public class B {

    @Id
    private Long id;

}
```

[image]
I need to write a query that fetches **B** and applies some `WHERE` criteria on **A** side.
Since the relationsip is modeled from **A** entity's side it's very easy to write a query that joins these itsself:

```
new JPAQuery<>(entityManager)
    .select(QB.b)
    .from(QA.a)
    .join(QA.a.listing,b)
    .where(QA.a.name.eq("test"))
    .fetch();
```

However since `A_B` table can be duplicated, this query can produce duplicate entries, which does not do for my scenario. So instead I need to start `FROM` `B` and `JOIN` `A`. And this is where I need help. I tried:

```
new JPAQuery<>(entityManager)
    .select(QB.b)
    .from(QB.b)
    .join(QA.a).on(QA.a.listing.any().eq(QB.b))
    .where(QA.a.name.eq("test"))
    .fetch();
```

But that does not work as `any()` merely produces a subselect, instead of many to many join.

How do I write this query in **Querydsl**?

Comment: What if you use `select(QB.b).distinct()` with first example?

Comment: @alexvaluiskyi yes, that's one of the options, but also that's flexing. It should be as simple to join many to many relationship from one side as from the other.